# How to create timer in javascript and count the clicks in specified time?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create timer in JavaScript,I will setup 10 secs and have user to click on images and display the counts when time stopped.

How can i achieve this task ?

index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="https://images.omkt.co/Files/402/15EAC0/19F78/8c2112737cfe4cd88779712a4906ef6d/0/hero_forte_2014--kia-1920x.png" height="150px" width="150px" id="clicks" onClick="clickMe()">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="https://images.omkt.co/Files/402/15EAC0/19F78/8c2112737cfe4cd88779712a4906ef6d/0/hero_forte_2014--kia-1920x.png" height="150px" width="150px" id="clicks" onClick="clickMe()">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="https://images.omkt.co/Files/402/15EAC0/19F78/8c2112737cfe4cd88779712a4906ef6d/0/hero_forte_2014--kia-1920x.png" height="150px" width="150px" id="clicks" onClick="clickMe()">
        </div>
    </div>

<div>
    <p id="clicks">0</p>
</div>
```

index.js

```
var clicks = 0;
function clickMe() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};

var digit=-1;
    var min=0;
    var time;
    var timer_is_on=0;

    function timer(){
            digit++;

            if(digit>59){
                min++;
                document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=min;
                digit=0;
            }
            // Put a "0" at the start of seconds
            if (digit <= 9)
                digit = '0' + digit;
                document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=digit;
    }
```

Comment: First of all you should know that a id should be unique. Otherwise document. will find a wrong element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable to the number of clicks, and increment it every time if the timer is running. To check if the timer is running, you can set another boolean variable to be `true` while the timer is running and `false` when it is done, so that you can check whether or not the timer is running.

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" id="img" />

<button id="button">Start Timer</button>
```

**JS**

```
var img = document.getElementById("img");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var timer = false;
var count = 0;
var t;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    timer = true;
    count = 0;
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Clicks on img: " + count);
    }, 10000);
});

img.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(timer) {
        count++;
    }
});
```

You can easily modify this so that you can click on any of your images, and you can change what you want to do with the resulting `count` (instead of just putting it in a popup).

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4o5duzds/) on JSfiddle.net.

---

**EDIT**

For your example:

**HTML**

Remove the `onclick` attributes and change the `id="clicks"` to `class="clicks"` in your existing HTML.

**JS**

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("clicks");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var timer = false;
var count = 0;
var clicked = [];
var t;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    timer = true;
    count = 0;
    clicked = [];
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = count;
        timer = false;
    }, 10000);
});

for(var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    img[i].id = i;
    img[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var index = this.id;
        if(timer && (clicked[index] == undefined)) {
            count++;
            clicked[index] = true;
        }
    });
}
```

See [new working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zc6sfhqu/3/) designed to work with *your* code.

Comment: Thanks for the response! how about if i have 5 pics and all of them have different ids how it will work with different ids  and second things if id is clicked already it should not be count

Comment: @aftab See updated post and JSFiddle. I modified it to work with your code.

Comment: sorry dont have access to jsfiddle but i dont see an updated code on stack

Comment: @aftab No access to JSFiddle? I didn't update my stackoverflow answer, only updated the JSFiddle link... I'll edit it again.

Comment: @aftab Sorry it took so long. Look at it now.

Comment: how i will see the result ?

Comment: Thank you for the help! It worked and you explain it very well. thanks again